# How to add pages to Refinery CMS testing dummy app database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, refinerycms

I created a Refinery CMS extension following [the extension guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started#extending-refinery-with-your-first-engine) and [the extension testing guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/testing/).

Some rspec unit tests pass and `http://localhost/the_extension` loads in a web browser. But now tests are failing because the dummy app has no pages (or any other db tables).

I tried just copying the dummy_dev file to dummy_test (and a whoooole bunch of other things), and that **works** (sort of) because when I run the dummy app (`cd spec/dummy; rvmsudo rails s -p 80 -e test`) the pages load in my browser, and when I query the pages table (`sqlite3 dummy_test 'select * from refinery_pages;`) there are pages.

But every time I run `cd vendor/extensions/the_extension; bundle exec rake spec` it deletes all the entries in the page table.

I tried adding this to `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
# Copy the prototype test database to the test database.
FileUtils.cp File.expand_path('../dummy_test_db_prototype', __FILE__), File.expand_path('../dummy/dummy_test', __FILE__)
```

But by the time the specs are run the test db has been deleted. The db is deleted after the specs are read in, because if I put the following at the bottom of `spec/features/refinery/the_extension/the_extension_spec.rb` the db still has pages:

```
# DEBUG
puts 'Querying test db:'
system "sqlite3 /some_app/vendor/extensions/the_extension/spec/dummy/dummy_test 'select * from refinery_pages;'"
puts 'Done querying.'
```

How do I make sure there are pages in the test database when the tests run?

Answer (score 0):

```
describe "stuff" do
  it "should do stuff" do
    before { Refinery::Page.create([{ title: 'home', link_url: '/' }]) }

    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this works. Unfortunately I still get the same error: `Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError: Unable to load URL: http://myapp.com/ because of error loading http://myapp.com/: Unknown error`. This is partly caused by `window.location.href = target_domain` on the front end. I read I shouldn't try to do API testing with Capybara, and it's proving true.